# Angular custom Pipe not found for only one component

Tags: angular, angular-material, pipe

I have a Pipe for translations with more languages.
After merge and solving confilics on git the compiler shows pipe not found. But this error is only shown in one component, it works fore everyone else.

I have inserted my Pipe in app.module.ts in declarations.

Dose someone else had this issue too?

**Edit:**
I deleted and recreated the component and now it works.

Comment: You should add the pipe in the component in which you use. Pipe's are not injected at root level.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara That's only valid for Angular 2, not any of the newer versions. It should suffice to declare and export a given pipe in module A and just import this module wherever needed.

Comment: Is that component in which it's not working is a part of app.module as well ?